# selenium can't locate tiktok upload zone

Tags: python, selenium

I can't upload videos to tiktok with selenium.
Hi, I can't upload videos to tiktok with selenium. When I give selenium the xpath to the upload area selenium doesn't find it.
if someone has solved this problem or has an alternative i would be grateful
ther is my code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath, options=chromeOptions)
driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/upload/?lang=en')
time.sleep(10)
ca = True
while ca:
    try:
       e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/button').click()
    except:
        print("nop")
        time.sleep(4)
```

console print nop and put the mouse on the upload area change nothing

html text of element :

```
<div class="jsx-2404389384 upload-card before-upload-stage"><img src="https://lf16-tiktok-common.ttwstatic.com/obj/tiktok-web-common-us/ies/creator_center/svgs/cloud-icon1.ecf0bf2b.svg" class="jsx-2404389384 cloud-icon"><div class="jsx-2404389384 text-main"><span class="css-1q42136">Sélectionne une vidéo à téléverser</span></div><div class="jsx-2404389384 text-sub"><span class="css-1wbo2p7">Ou fais glisser un fichier</span></div><div class="jsx-2404389384 text-video-info"><div class="jsx-2404389384"><span class="css-tad11f">MP4 ou WebM</span></div><div class="jsx-2404389384"><span class="css-tad11f">Résolution 720x1280 ou supérieure</span></div><div class="jsx-2404389384"><span class="css-tad11f">Jusqu'à 10 minutes</span></div><div class="jsx-2404389384"><span class="css-tad11f">Moins de 2 Go</span></div></div><div class="jsx-2404389384 file-select-button"><button class="css-ku5jwq"><div class="css-4c683v"><div class="css-1z070dx">Choisis un fichier</div></div></button></div></div>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element

Comment: ok plz wait 3 min

Comment: ok it's done ! it is what you want?